# how did get.code-industry.net land in my in /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, configuration

I looked into my hosts file just now and saw this :

```
0.0.0.0 get.code-industry.net
```

I don't remember putting that in and I don't like the look of it at all.

Any idea what it's about and how it got there?

UPDATE:
*I've learned that the entry will disable requests going to that domain name so it seems to be harmless unless I want to go there.
Even so. I don't remember entering it. Either my memory(human) is faulty or some process has gained root access to my `/etc/hosts`  file. Perhaps an install process? Even so it seems a rather odd thing for an installation process to do*.

Comment: The domain name may be coming from this software: https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/ . Do you have this installed?

Comment: @Haxiel I do not. However that is a useful comment.

Answer (score 4):

For me it's due to installing *Master PDF Editor Free edition v4* from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/masterpdfeditor-free) on ArchLinux.

This host mapping is made in the [masterpdfeditor-free.install](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/masterpdfeditor-free.install?h=masterpdfeditor-free) file.

```bsh
post_install() {
  echo '0.0.0.0 get.code-industry.net' >> /etc/hosts
}
post_remove() {
  sed -i '/get\.code-industry\.net/d' /etc/hosts
}
```